# SVN Diff Replaced Files

Tags: svn, version-control, diff

I am merging a branch into the trunk with `--reintegrate`, and I came across a file that got replaced sometime between when I created the branch and now. This means I deleted the file at some point and committed, then recreated it later on and committed again. When I run `svn diff` on the file, I get no output.

Is there a way to view changes in the file between the version from before I deleted it and now, after I added it back? I don't want to check out a whole new trunk *and* a whole new version of this branch, and the URL names tend to be pretty long so I would rather not do an `svn cat` or `svn diff` on them, even if I could remember the whole URL.

I would like to do this directly with `svn diff`, using just the path of the file from the current working directory. Ideally, any solution would allow for multiple replacements, though this is pretty rare. Also, it should work on directories: it should diff any files that existed in said directories both before the directory was deleted and now. If no files existed at both times, the diff could be empty.

**How do I view differences in a replaced file in SVN using just `svn diff`?**

I am using `svn 1.7` (yes, this is a really old version).